# undeline text button only if it pressed

Tags: react-native

I'm setting up a new component and I want to underline the text button only if it pressed and when I pressed another button so the underline will disappears and the new button will be underlined...

This is for a new component

```
<View style={Style.tabsContainer}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text style={{
            color: 'white',
            textDecorationLine: 'underline',
            fontSize: 16,
            margin: 2,
            padding: 2
        }}>Products</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text style={{
            color: 'white',
            textDecorationLine: 'underline',
            fontSize: 16,
            margin: 2,
            padding: 2
        }}>Categories</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text style={{
            color: 'white',
            textDecorationLine: 'underline',
            fontSize: 16,
            margin: 2,
            padding: 2
        }}>Warehouse</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text style={{
            color: 'white',
            textDecorationLine: 'underline',
            fontSize: 16,
            margin: 2,
            padding: 2
        }}>Upcs</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text style={{
            color: 'white',
            textDecorationLine: 'underline',
            fontSize: 16,
            margin: 2,
            padding: 2
        }}>Tags</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

I'm trying to make a situation that only when I press one of the buttons then it will be underlined and if I press another button then only it will be underlined and the rest will not and so on ...

Comment: What's the issue? Have you made any attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `state`. Here is a sample code for two buttons, you could reflect for the rest in the same manner.

Firstly, in your Main class, add a constuctor and declare states within,

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  button1: null,
  button2: null
  };
}
```

Finally, `onPress` of a particular component set the appropriate states and assign state values to the `textDecorationLine` prop.

```
  <View style={Style.tabsContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
               this.setState({button1:"underline",button2:null});
           }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', textDecorationLine: this.state.button1, fontSize: 16, margin: 2, padding: 2 }}>Products</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            this.setState({button1:null,button2:"underline"});
          }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', textDecorationLine: this.state.button2, fontSize: 16, margin: 2, padding: 2 }}>Categories</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
```

I hope i could help. Do comment for further guidance.

**Update** (Regarding your query in comments)**:**

`createTabNavigator` has 2 parameters `RouteConfigs and BottomTabNavigatorConfig;`

After adding the `RouteConfigs` alterate the `BottomTabNavigatorConfig` with below code, you will get clarity.

`tabBarOptions` prop is used to get the effect. Refer this link to get more insights [BottomTabNavigatorConfig](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#bottomtabnavigatorconfig)

```
export default createTabNavigator(
  {
    Page1: {
      screen: Page1,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Page1"
      }
    },
    Page2: {
      screen: Page2,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Page2"
      }
    },
    Page3: {
      screen: Page3,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Page3"
      }
    },
  },
  {
     //BottomTabNavigatorConfig here
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarPosition: "top",
    lazy: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      scrollEnabled: true,
      upperCaseLabel: false,
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#39b4ea",
        borderWidth: 0.1
        //#286ec0
      },

      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        textAlign: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        fontFamily: "Inter-Regular"
      },
      style: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
        shadowColor: "black",
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        elevation: 2
      },
      activeTintColor: "#39b4ea",
      inactiveTintColor: "#7c7c7c"
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: How can I do it with tab navigator and not buttons?

Comment: tab navigator in the sense react-navigation tab navigator or a simple component mimicking a tab navigator ?

Comment: tab navigator in the sense react-navigation tab navigator .

Comment: I need the tabs in the up of the screen and not at the bottom

Comment: The above code will work for the same. In the above code I have set the `tabBarPosition` prop to `top`

Comment: Hi Ron, I can show you my code that you will explain to me exactly how to do it because I use with stack navigator also to arrive at the page where the tabs should be in.
s I'm scared to get confused.
how can I show you my code?

Comment: This blog will give you insights of how to use a tab-navigator [tab-navigator](https://codeburst.io/ricky-figures-it-out-simple-react-native-tabnavigator-using-react-navigation-592945a3b211). The only modication you would have to do is make `tabBarPosition: ‘top’` in `BottomTabNavigatorConfig`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use STATE and change state according to your needs. Here is something that hopefully will help you:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component(){

constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        decorationProducts: 'none',
        decorationCategories: 'none',
        decorationWarehouse: 'none',
        decorationUpcs: 'none',
        decorationTags: 'none',
    };
    this._setDecorations = this._setDecorations.bind(this);
}

_setDecorations(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5){
    this.setState({
        decorationProducts: d1,
        decorationCategories: d2,
        decorationWarehouse: d3,
        decorationUpcs: d4,
        decorationTags: d5,
    });
}

render(){
    return(
        <View style={Style.tabsContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this._setDecorations('underline','none','none', 'none', 'none')}}>
                <Text style={{ color: 'white', textDecorationLine: this.state.decorationProducts, fontSize: 16, margin: 2, padding: 2 }}>Products</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this._setDecorations('none','underline','none', 'none', 'none')}}>
                <Text style={{ color: 'white', textDecorationLine: this.state.decorationCategories, fontSize: 16, margin: 2, padding: 2 }}>Categories</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this._setDecorations('none','none','underline', 'none', 'none')}}>
                <Text style={{ color: 'white', textDecorationLine: this.state.decorationWarehouse, fontSize: 16, margin: 2, padding: 2 }}>Warehouse</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this._setDecorations('none','none','none', 'underline', 'none')}}>
                <Text style={{ color: 'white', textDecorationLine: this.state.decorationUpcs, fontSize: 16, margin: 2, padding: 2 }}>Upcs</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this._setDecorations('none','none','none', 'none', 'underline')}}>
                <Text style={{ color: 'white', textDecorationLine: this.state.decorationTags, fontSize: 16, margin: 2, padding: 2 }}>Tags</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```